# Simple command-line loop in Linux shell

Tags: linux, command-line

I have identically named files in 4 subfolders of folder `build` named:

- release-iphoneos
- release-iphonesimulator
- debug-iphoneos
- debug-iphonesimulator

I want to copy these files to an identical directory structure in a folder `sdk`, on the command-line - but not using a script.

What I thought I should be able to do is something like:

```
for C in (release debug); for T in (iphoneos iphonesimulator); cp build/$C-$T/*.a sdk/$C-$T
```

But I'm not a Linux guy and I can't get it to work even after looking up for loops. Can it be done on a single line fairly easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your approach:

- `(A B)` can only be used for array assignment (e.g., `C=(A B)`), not creating one on-the-fly.

  However, *for* does not require an array, so `for C in A B` will work just fine.
- The proper syntax for `for` loops is `for ... in ...; do ..., done`.

This command should work just fine:

```
for C in release debug; do for T in iphoneos iphonesimulator; do cp build/$C-$T/*.a sdk/$C-$T; done; done
```

Note that this requires the proper folders in *sdk* to exist already.

However, as @Robertof already showed, there are ways to archive this without any loops at all.

---

If you want to copy **all** files from the directories (i.e., `*.a` matches all of them), yu can use his command or this slight simplification:

```
cp -R build/{release,debug}-iphone{os,simulator} sdk
```

How it works:

- The shell will perform [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), so the command that will be actually executed is this one:

  ```
  cp -r build/release-iphoneos build/release-iphonesimulator build/debug-iphoneos build/debug-iphonesimulator sdk
  ```
- The `-r` switch makes *cp* recursive, i.e., it will copy entire directories instead of just files.

---

If you want to copy only the `*.a* files (i.e., there are others), you're better of using these commands:

```
cd build
cp --parents {release,debug}-iphone{os,simulator}/*.a ../sdk
```

How it works:

- Again, brace expansion is performed as before.
- The `--parents` switch makes *cp* use the full source file name for the destination, i.e., files from `release-iphoneos` will be copied to `../sdk/release-iphoneos`.

---

Finally, a word of advice:

When experimenting with *cp* commands, always use the `-i` switch. It make *cp* interactive, meaning that it will prompt before overwriting anything.

Comment: It was only a pseudo command :) Good comment about `-i` although for testing I tend to make it `echo` the statement rather than perform it, so I can unroll my loops/functions and see exactly what they will do.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
cp -R build/{release-iphoneos,release-iphonesimulator,debug-iphoneos,debug-iphonesimulator} sdk/
```